# How to structure a git project/repo consisting of a few dozen production instances that are based on the same core but are all slightly different?

Tags: git, github, versioning

This is purely hypothetical, I'm not asking specifically about WordPress, I'm just trying to paint a picture here.

Let's say we have a WordPress site . We have that code on git, the repo is called `Base` and we follow a fairly standard gitflow branching scheme, i.e. `main`, `release`, `develop`, `feature` etc.

`Base` is not an actual live WordPress site but is the core code we develop - add features, fix bugs, etc. We have a few dozen slightly different cloned versions that will be deployed as standalone independent live Wordpress sites that are all identical to `Base`, but all have slight adjustments made to them.

For instance - each site has a unique background image. All are different languages and string values are stored in a i18n .json file (let's ignore databases for now). Perhaps 2 of them need slight CSS additions, maybe 4 of them require an additional module (let's ignore that composer or any other package manager exists), etc.

We want to store all alternate sites fully on git in a "running state" (i.e., all dependencies, modules, etc. are stored as well), and at their core are entirely `Base` but slightly altered and include images, module files, etc.

What would be the best approach here?

- Have each website as a branch in the `Base` repo with their own gitflow branches i.e. `site3-main`, `site3-release`, etc in that same repo?
- Have each site on it's own repo and pull commits from the `main` branch of `Base` so all websites have their core up to date?
- Fork them from `Base` and pull updates the same as above?
- Some other way?

The intent isn't to have derivatives/forks that go off and become standalone. The idea is to only develop on `Base` and apply the same commits made to `main` to the other versions. If needed to tweak a specific site (i.e. change i18n strings on one particular clone of `Base`) have the ability to have that as a commit made specifically to that site that doesn't alter `Base` or any other "clone".

Updates only go from `Base` to all "clones". At no point do "clones" get merged/pulled into `Base`. A "clone" can be altered with slight tweaks that only apply to it and it only.

Potential headaches of merge conflicts aside, what do you think the best git structure would be for a project like this? Thanks!

Comment: Git isn't really a deployment tool. It stores software and tracks changes. The differences you are talking about are more like configuration or content, and should handled outside of Git.

Comment: @chepner You're not wrong. But what's the approach of updating the two dozen sites from the core `Base`? Copy/paste the updated .CSS file from `Base` to every FTP server for each site? What if 3 of the sites have an additional style that the others don't? - manually remember to modify .CSS files prior to upload those 3 sites? Having that on git would involve initially adding that .CSS code 3 times to each target site, but later we wouldn't have to deal that and only upload each sites `main` branch. I may be asking the wrong questions here, but I'm not seeing how to manage this outside of git.

Comment: I want to stress that this is an example. The actual codebase is non configurable in the modern sense. Dealing with these slight alterations per instance is a nightmare even though they are minor (in my hypothetical example each site has a different bg color) yet the check list for slight alterations is becoming non trivial to manage manually. Git solves some issues, not all, adds potential headaches like merge conflicts, but it's better than 20 pages of which code block to copy/paste back in after uploading an updated core file to a "clone". I'm just conflicted with how to structure this.